# Parsing Ofx file with java

Tags: java, parsing, ofx

I am currently trying to read an ofx file with java.
But I get the following error: `Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException` (for the 2nd line). I am using OFx4j. Could you please give me some tips on that one?

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
String filename=new String("C:\\file.ofx");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
    NanoXMLOFXReader nano = new NanoXMLOFXReader();

    try
    {
        nano.parse(stream);
        System.out.println("woooo It workssss!!!!");
    }
    catch (OFXParseException e)
    {
    }
```

Thanks for your comments, I made some changes:

```
String FILE_TO_READ = "C:\\file.ofx";


    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_READ);
        NanoXMLOFXReader nano = new NanoXMLOFXReader();


        nano.parse(file);
        System.out.println("woooo It workssss!!!!");
    }
    catch (OFXParseException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Message : "+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Other Message : "+e1.getMessage());
    }
```

But now I am getting this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/n3/nanoxml/XMLParseException
    at OfxTest.afficherFichier(OfxTest.java:31)
    at OfxTest.main(OfxTest.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.n3.nanoxml.XMLParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more

I am trying to figure it out. I believe it can't find the XMLParseException. But I am not sure.

Comment: You are opening up a stream but not checking for exception.

Comment: Don't write `new String("C:\\file.ofx")`, just write `String filename = "C:\\file.ofx";` There is no reason to explicitly create a new `String` object from a literal string.

Comment: Well noticed @Jesper, after reading his/her exception, I jump directly to input stream code :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second problem that you're encountering: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/n3/nanoxml/XMLParseException" means that you haven't included the NanoXML library from here: http://devkix.com/nanoxml.php

You will also need the Apache Commons Logging library, as NanoXML appears to be dependent on this. Available here: http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are not catching `FileNotFoundException`. Also although this is not relevant to your error message but as best practice you should always close you file stream in the finally block like I have below. There is also no need to do to new String() on the file name either.

Add this catch block for the `FileNotFoundException`:-

```
    String filename = "C:\\file.ofx";
    FileInputStream file = null;
    NanoXMLOFXReader nano = null;
    try
    {
         file = new FileInputStream(filename);
         nano = new NanoXMLOFXReader();
        nano.parse(stream);
        System.out.println("woooo It workssss!!!!");
    }
    catch (OFXParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }finally{
        if(file!=null){
           file.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it okay to open a stream outside try{}catch{} block? as FileNotFoundException will occur while "FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);" is called, yes?

Comment: @krio - Sorry I was in a hurry and wrote it too quickly ... I fixed the code snippet now. try it now. It's a simple issue, he is just not catching an exception .. :)

Comment: Let Bon_chan try it! as I answered it too! anyway got confused after reading your code and didn't wanted to downvote as I sense that was an honest mistake ;) cheers

Comment: @krio - yup, thanks for noticing it. I also added the file close for OP in the finnaly block since I noticed he does not have a close statement in his code.

Comment: Check question's comment section, Well noticed by Jesper lol!

Comment: @krio oh yeah thats right. Anyway there are too many things to fix there.

Comment: @krio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2974/discussion-between-coolbeans-and-krio)